# Animar item ao :hover e voltar com outras propriedades

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Tendo um item, de exemplo, um ícone. Necessito que seu estado inicial seja cinza e assim seu CSS será:

```
filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.5);
transition: 1s;
```

Após isso, no `:hover` o ícone precisa aumentar, girar e receber cor:

```
filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
transition-duration: 1s;
transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-15deg);
```

Porém, ao retirar o mouse precisa continuar com a cor e com o tamanho original. Aqui está o que já consegui, porém ao retirar o mouse o ícone precisa continuar colorido com seu tamanho de início: [ver vídeo](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1GF84T0fAFTdMECwSBb93oRvCWph3k2HS)

Comment: *"ao retirar o mouse precisa continuar com a cor*" e não poderia já começar com essa cor? vc quer um controle de estado do elemento, algo como "hover ao menos uma vez", e esse tipo de coisa não é feita com `css`, teria de fazer com `javascript`

Comment: Creio que terás que usar JS, porque o :hover muda as propriedades do elemento enquanto o mouse está sobre ele. Ao retirar o mouse, volta pro estado original.

Comment: Só com CSS não tem jeito, pq não da para vc manter o estado de hover após tirar o mouse do elemeto. Vc até consegue ir com uma animação e voltar com outra. Mas manter a animação da volta depois de tirar o mouse vc não consegue

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo retorno! E utilizando JS? Vocês já teriam uma base pronta para eu entender como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só com CSS não é possível pois o `:hover` muda temporariamente as propriedades do elemento que volta ao seu estado original após perder o `:hover`.

Com JavaScript você pode usar o evento `mouseout` para alterar a propriedade `filter` quando o elemento perder o `:hover`, ficando permanentemente com o `grayscale` em `0%` e o `opacity` em `1`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   document.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){
      
      if(~e.target.className.indexOf("icone")){
         e.target.style.filter = "grayscale(0%) opacity(1)";
      }
      
   });
   
});
```

```css
.icone{
   filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.5);
   transition: 1s;
}

.icone:hover{
   filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
   transition-duration: 1s;
   transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1060/small/icon-icx-logo.png?1547035003" class="icone">
<img src="https://www.oxbridgeacademy.edu.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/time-icon.png" class="icone">
```

Veja que o elemento precisa ter a classe `.icone` (ou qualquer outra que você quiser).

Comment: funcionou muito bem sua solução. Me ajudou muito, espero que ajude outros também. Obrigado pela ajuda!